# Showing Swi-prolog backtrace?

Tags: debugging, prolog, swi-prolog, backtrace, debug-backtrace

I figure it may not be built to do that but I might ask.

I want to run a simple cli application and have it show the backtrace in case of error.

`swipl -f test.pl -g test(X)`

This runs the goal *test* in the program.

`ERROR: -g test(X): Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`

However, it doesn't show the full backtrace. What I need to do is every time, open the GUI, type *guitracer,trace*, run it, etc. That shows the program can keep a backtrace.

I figure it may not be built to do that but I might ask.

Comment: Did you try searching for "backtrace" before you asked? In roughly 5 seconds I found this: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/prolog_stack.pl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't believe I got lost in debugger pages. As said in comments,

`:- use_module(library(prolog_stack)).`

is enough.